# How to change xrandr brightness without losing gamma settings?

Tags: xorg, display, xrandr, colors, gamma

KDE's Night Color feature I guess uses `xrandr`'s gamma functionality, but I was hoping to adjust the brightness of my display using it. Unfortunately, doing so like this loses the "night color" because it resets the gamma:

```
xrandr --output DP-0 --brightness .8
```

Is there some way to query the currently applied values from `xrandr` so I can reapply them?

Comment: By the way, does night color work in Wayland session? xrandr does not work in Wayland, so it may be a way to figure out whether night color does use wayland.

Comment: Sadly, I can't get really get Wayland to work on my machine.

Comment: There was a typo in my comment.  *it may be a way to figure out whether night color does use xrandr*

Answer (score 1):

**To change brightness independently of `xrandr`:**

From my tests on my stock Ubuntu 20.04 system, it seems the input and output of the `xgamma` tool are completely independent to `xrandr`. So, if you change the brightness using `xgamma -gamma 0.8` then that shouldn't affect the `xrandr` night light settings :)

---

**To query the currently applied gamma values of `xrandr`:**

```
xrandr --verbose | grep "Gamma"
```

I had a look at `man xrandr` for documentation, and it seems the `--verbose` flag gives out the details for the gamma.

It does say

> Please note that the gamma and brightness informations are only approximations of the complete color profile stored in the server.

and my tests seem to show that the value output by this is not the same as what is passed during input.

For example, if I enter `xrandr --output eDP-1 --gamma 2:0.5:0.2` and then `xrandr --verbose | grep "Gamma"`, it outputs:

```
    Gamma:      0.50:2.0:5.0
```

I closed Redshift before running these tests, so hopefully that didn't interfere.

There might be some way to figure out a transformation to interpret the value, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: The value to enter in the command line option are the inverse of the value written in the ouput: 1/2.0 = 0.5, 1/0.5 = 2.0, 1/0.2=5.0 (not sure why! In any case that doesn't seem to be a good solution for Night Color, see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

Cross-posting my answer [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003101/how-to-use-xrandr-gamma-for-gnome-night-light-like-usage/1408202#1408202):

For best result adjusting brightness with `xrandr` and still using KDE's Night Color feature, I suggest to install `redshift` (`apt install redshift`) and to use it either as:

```
redshift -oP -O 4500 -b 0.5
```

for a temperature of 4500 and brightness of 0.5, or in combination with `xrandr` (and, optionally, `xrandr-invert-colors` to invert colours):

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.5
xrandr-invert-colors
redshift -o -O 4500
```

Note that calling `xrandr` on its own will cancel any redshift effect. The `-P` option of `redshift` also resets the screen brightness and color instead of incrementally superimposing adjustments. Incremental adjustments (no `-P` option) are needed if using in conjunction with `xrandr` like in the second use case.

Finally, instead of using `xrandr-invert-colors`, one can also use a negative brightness value in `xrandr` (but not in `redshift`), but the result is not as nice.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer to my full question, but it turns out [the brightness is applied by adjusting the gamma](https://linuxhint.com/display_brightness_commandline/)

> Note that it doesn’t change hardware level brightness, it is just a software level filter with adjusted gamma values.

So presumably I can find these values somewhere.